# Shopware 6 administration build only plugin

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Is there a command to build only the administration part of a specified plugin? Right now I am building the whole administration to build the public resources for the plugin, which of course takes more time. Since every plugin has it's own resources, shouldn't it be possible to do this?

Comment: i think that is not possible, the build scripts always builds the whole administration with all active plugins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Shopware 6.4.8.0 it seems to be possible to only build the extensions (not a single one, but at least only extensions) by adding the environment variable `SHOPWARE_ADMIN_BUILD_ONLY_EXTENSIONS=1`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it provides a solution

Answer (score 3):

There are no out-of-the-box scripts to selectively build only one module.

The build is based on one single webpack config in `vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration` which includes each extension's code as as submodule.

If you are asking to speed up development, you might want to use `bin/watch-administration.sh` which should only rebuild changed files when you save them.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the watch-mode, but I just wondered if it's possible to build only one plugin. But apparently, there is not...